# When one monkey accelerates up a rope, what happens to the other?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces

The question is:

Two equal weight monkeys each hang from the ends of a rope passing over a weightless, frictionless pulley. If one accelerates up the rope, what happens to the other?

I'm going to assume here that if one monkey climbs, the other monkey goes up (I tried to imagine how it would look in real life). But in physical terms, why would this be? Because of the additional force exerted by the climbing monkey?

Comment: See also: [Movement of man and ladder and their center of mass](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/58193/movement-of-man-and-ladder-and-their-center-of-mass)