# A pulley problem,with man walking on ladder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work, free-body-diagram, string

**Background/question**:Suppose I have  stationary light, smooth pulley can rotate without friction about a fixed horizontal axis. A light rope passes over the pulley. One end of the rope supports a ladder with a man and the other end supports a counterweight of mass $M$.

The mass of the man is $m$. initially, the centre of mass of the counterweight is at a height h from that of man as shown in Fig.
If the man starts to climb up the ladder slowly, how can I calculate work done by him to reach his centre of mass in level with that of the counterweight?

Here is a diagram:

[image]

It is clear that the ladder must be of mass $M-m$. Now the let $y$ be the distance moved by $M$ when the man comes in height with the $M$ Thus the displacement in the centre of mass  of system consisting of the ladder, man, block $$\Delta r=\frac{My-(M-m)y+m(h+y)}{M-m+m+M}=\frac{2my+mh}{2M}$$

**Problem i am facing**:

This is what I have done so far. My concept is a bit flimsy here, is it that only the man is doing work? If not how do I find the work done by tension, the ladder, etc I guess there is only a difference in signs.I think I am missing one more condition .

Please note that  I am not necessarily looking for a complete solution but merely an idea of what other concept I should apply here.

**Source** :B.M Sharma Mechanics Vol-2 :Subjective question no:2

**Related Posts**:

[Why is the centre of mass displaced even when external force is 0?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/431252/why-is-the-centre-of-mass-displaced-even-when-external-force-is-0?rq=1)

[Movement of man and ladder and their center of mass](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/58193/movement-of-man-and-ladder-and-their-center-of-mass?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Hint:if we consider man as system we can write : work done by man + work done by normal from ladder = change in mechanical energy simce normal by ladder and tension in rope are equal therefore we can write the same equation for block