# Why does the centre of mass move?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Consider this problem:

> A stationary pulley carries a rope, one end of which supports a ladder with a man and the other end a counterweight of mass $M$. The man of mass $m$ climbs up a distance $l$ with respect to the ladder and then stops. What is the displacement of the centre of mass of the system?

Consider the counterweight, the man and the ladder to be one system. Their centre of mass doesn't accelerate if the external force on the system is zero, so the centre isn't displaced.

What causes the acceleration in this case? Is it friction due to the pulley?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/602533/a-pulley-problem-with-man-walking-on-ladder

Comment: @BowlOfRed Yes, thanks.